# Identifying server timeout quickly in iPhone

Tags: iphone

I am connecting my iPhone application to JBOSS server.  When the JBoss server is down, the iPHone timesout while connecting.  It takes lot of time to timeout.  Is there a quick way to identify if my application server is down.  I think Reachability example demoes if the server machine is down and not if the application server is down.  ANy help or advise would be appreciated.

Comment: I am not using ASIHTTPRequest.  Should I use this?  Will this solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Lets generalize the problem, so that its easier to visualize the problem and its solution.

Suppose, Your App is the only app connected to the server. When it sends a query, it get a response. Now you can assume if the server is OK, you should be able to receive a response in 5 sec's but if the server is down you will never receive a response.

This assumption breaks down the problem into two variables, 5 and infinity but you dont want to wait till the end of time to receive an answer, so you introduce a timeout value. Let say 5 min's. Now your variables are 5 and 360 sec. All is good but you dont want to wait 5 min (360 sec) if the server is down but you do want to wait 30 or 60 sec's if the connection is slow.

What you need is a another service, which monitors your server every (5-360) / 2 sec. Now when you query your server, you can wait till (5-360) / 2 sec before sending out a quick query to the third party service to check if your server is up or down.

This way you can reduce the query time out by (5-360) / 2 + the time it takes for the third party to answer your query.

Answer (score 0):

See the docs on how to create your NSURLRequest: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/ipad/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html

You can specify a timeout with requestWithUrl:cachePolicy:timeoutInterval: